# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'country') Whenever I search for a city

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api-key, openweathermap

I am using Open weather map and Reactjs.

The problem is found in my `WeatherContainer` component.

I want my search bar to work. But whenever I search for a city I get this error:

[image: console error]

I have tried changing the API key but it does nothing.

The code error line is pointing at :

[image: source error]

I get my data like this:

**WeatherContainer.tsx:**

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState({
    city: "",
    country: "",
    temperature: 0,
    description: "",
    icon: "",
    humidity: "",
    feels: "",
    visibility: "",
    pressure: "",
    longitude: "",
    latitude: "",
    windSpeed: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fetchedData)
      setWeather({
        city: fetchedData.name,
        country: fetchedData.sys.country,
        temperature: Math.floor(fetchedData.main.temp - 273),
        description: fetchedData.weather[0].description,
        icon: `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${fetchedData.weather[0].icon}.png`,
        humidity: fetchedData.main.humidity + "%",
        feels: Math.floor(fetchedData.main.feels_like - 273) + "°C",
        visibility: fetchedData.visibility + "m",
        pressure: fetchedData.main.pressure + "hPa",
        longitude: fetchedData.coord.lon,
        latitude: fetchedData.coord.lat,
        windSpeed: fetchedData.wind.speed + "m/s",
      });
  }, [fetchedData]);
```

---

Edit:

```
This is how I defined fetchedData

export const WeatherContainer = ({
  fetchedData,
  error,
}: {
  fetchedData: any;
  error: string;
}) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({
    city: "",
    country: "",
    temperature: 0,
    description: "",
    icon: "",
    humidity: "",
    feels: "",
    visibility: "",
    pressure: "",
    longitude: "",
    latitude: "",
    windSpeed: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fetchedData)
      setWeather({
        city: fetchedData.name,
        country: fetchedData.sys.country,
        temperature: Math.floor(fetchedData.main.temp - 273),
        description: fetchedData.weather[0].description,
        icon: `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${fetchedData.weather[0].icon}.png`,
        humidity: fetchedData.main.humidity + "%",
        feels: Math.floor(fetchedData.main.feels_like - 273) + "°C",
        visibility: fetchedData.visibility + "m",
        pressure: fetchedData.main.pressure + "hPa",
        longitude: fetchedData.coord.lon,
        latitude: fetchedData.coord.lat,
        windSpeed: fetchedData.wind.speed + "m/s",
      });
  }, [fetchedData]);
```

I used this API https://openweathermap.org/current. I just tried to follow this documentation so I copied the link to API they have.

---

Edit # 2

This is the file Where I make the connection:

```
const API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

export const getWeatherCoordinates = async (
  LAT: number,
  LON: number
): Promise<any> => {
  const API_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${LAT}&lon=${LON}&appid=${API_KEY}`;

  const respCoordinates = await fetch(API_URL);
  const dataCoordinates = await respCoordinates.json();
  return dataCoordinates;
};
export const getWeatherSearch = async (CITY: string): Promise<any> => {
  const API_CITY = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${CITY}&appid={API_KEY}`;
  const respCity = await fetch(API_CITY);
  const dataCity = await respCity.json();
  return dataCity;
};
```

The API response is :

```
{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}
```

[image: api link]

Comment: Can you show us how you define fetchedData, and how you call to API looks like?

Comment: @Terminat  Check again, please.

Comment: Could you also add the actual response from the API.

Comment: Based on the console image you've provided, looks like you are not providing an API key at all, instead you left the template `{API_KEY}` at the end of the fetch URL. You've mentioned that you tried providing a different key. Was that key valid? Did you get a proper response?

Comment: @tomleb No any of the keys I tried was valid.  API_KEY is a const that brings my API_KEY above the code.

Comment: @Erick please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error image you posted and the source code, it seems like missed a `$` sign in front of `{API_KEY}` in `getWeatherSearch` :

```
export const getWeatherSearch = async (CITY: string): Promise<any> => {
  const API_CITY = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${CITY}&appid=${API_KEY}`; // <- HERE 
  const respCity = await fetch(API_CITY);
  const dataCity = await respCity.json();
  return dataCity;
};
```